# One Hot Encoding a 2 categorical variable

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

For variables with two categories, do they need to be One Hot Encoded? In my dataset I have a binary variable as either 1 or 0. Do I need to transform that variable in a pipeline for my model or do I leave it as is?

```
variable = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,1,0]).reshape(-1,1)
ohc = OneHotEncoder()
ohc.fit(variable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is already binary (only two classes: 0 and 1), you can say that this variable is already One Hot Encoded, so you don't need to to `OneHotEncoder` again with Sklearn function.

Moreover, in general terms, if you binary variable is categorical, you have to transform it to numerical using `LabelEncoder`. Anyway, in your example, your variable was already numerical.